# Php and mysql date and time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am new in php and I saw some programmer store datetime in database by php `date()` or mysql `NOW()` or take column as timestamp. I want to know that the difference between these three is and also how to convert these three formats to users local time worldwide.

Comment: thanks all , but i am confuse how to convert this format to user local time

Answer (score 0):

1. As per the mysql's law you can have only one `timestamp` field,no
   restrictions for having number of `datetime` field..
2. You can set the
       timestamp field for `onupdate current timestamp` or `current
       timestamp`..And these field type not affecting the `date insert
       method`..
3. If you are using `date()` function you can  set your own
       date format..But not in the `now()`

For date format the syntax check this article https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp

Finaly `Datetime and timestamp`is mysql
date() and NOW()`is php`

Comment: Please,  link to the official documentation whenever possible. w3schools has a terrible reputation for being out of date and inaccurate.

Comment: Thats is outdated..but not wrong right?..He is just  beginner ..Thats only enough easy to takeoff from the bottom for him

Comment: I'm mentioning this *because* of the beginner angle. w3schools is full of outdated junk which causes a lot of harm to new developers. The official documentation is significantly higher quality and is always up to date. Where it's missing information, the comments are actually quite helpful.

Comment: I agree buddy..but you can feel that? his question reveals that still he couldn't get the difference between what is php and what is mysql...Thats why i have putted the simple and easily understandable one..sorry..:)

Comment: That's why a link to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is better. What you have there is a liability, I'm serious. That site has damaged a generation of new programmers.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things to consider:

- `TIMESTAMP` columns are limited to dates between 1931 and 2038, as they're [32-bit timestamp values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).
- `DATETIME` columns can go up to the year 9999. While they don't auto-populate like `TIMESTAMP` values do by default, they're less restricted, you can have as many as you want per table.

When inserting times your PHP clock and your database clock might differ slightly. Using [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) can help narrow that gap, but drifts do happen. PHP's [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function requires formatting into [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for inserting (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`). The MySQL `NOW()` function does not, same with `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`.

I strongly recommend using UTC time in your database for a few reasons:

- If you store in local time you'll need to store the time-zone as well, and those can change in wild and bizarre ways.
- You may need to accommodate other time zones in the future, which means you might have multiple local times in your data where each record might have a different meaning from others.
- Your server might get moved between time-zones which can shift all your data.

So store with UTC and render out as local times based on the user's time-zone preference or some sensible default for your application. Remember, time formatting is often a fussy thing, every country has different date formatting standards, and even a single country might have multiple preferences for long-form, short-form, or numerical forms.